# Deleting XML namespace while ignoring the one at the root

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have an xml.

```
<ClinicalDocuments>

<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:axolotl="urn:axolotl-com:pdo">
        <realmCode xmlns="" code="US"/>
        <typeId xmlns="" extension="POCD_HD000040" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3"/>
        <templateId xmlns="" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1"/>
        <templateId xmlns="" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1"/>
        <templateId xmlns="" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1.1"/>
        <templateId xmlns="" root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3"/>
        <templateId xmlns="" root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1"/>
        <templateId xmlns="" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.88.11.32.1"/>
        <id xmlns="" root="006e50e9-29b5-4ab2-8c0b-202819b39646"/>
blah
blah
</ClinicalDocument>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
blah
blah
.
.
</ClinicalDocument>

</ClinicalDocuments>
```

xmlns="" is overritting the the main xmlns.

I want to delete all other instances on xmlns="" while keeping the one at the root node "ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:axolotl="urn:axolotl-com:pdo"

There are many other xmlns="" in the entire xml.
Please help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. First, `ClinicalDocument` is not the root node. Next, its children are in no-namespace and the `xmlns=""` decalration is required to make that clear. Do you want move them to their parent's  namespace? This will effectively change your XML schema, so think carefully about the consequences before you do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't manipulate namespace declarations directly in XSLT. You should make sure each element in the result tree is in the correct namespace, and the namespace declarations will then be taken care of automatically.

For example, if you don't want `xmlns=""` to appear on the `realmCode` element, then you should make sure that you generate the `realmCode` element in the same namespace as its parent element. That can be done by a template rule such as:

```
<xsl:template match="realmCode">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But I want to use the same name space as its parent. So Is there a way of  making the  xmlns="" into xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" ?

Comment: You don't seem to have understood my answer at all. Stop worrying about namespace declarations. Just create elements in the required namespace, and the namespace declarations will take care of themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all instances of `xmlns=""`. This XML passes validation and `xmlns` from `<ClinicalDocument>` wont be overwritten anymore:

```
<ClinicalDocuments>
    <ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:axolotl="urn:axolotl-com:pdo">
        <realmCode code="US"/>
        <typeId extension="POCD_HD000040" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3"/>
        <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1"/>
        <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1"/>
        <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1.1"/>
        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3"/>
        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1"/>
        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.88.11.32.1"/>
        <id root="006e50e9-29b5-4ab2-8c0b-202819b39646"/>
blah
blah
    </ClinicalDocument>
    <ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
blah
blah...
    </ClinicalDocument>
</ClinicalDocuments>
```

Comment: But i will have around 80,000 incoming stream of these xmls. So we cant think of deleting manually. Is there a way of atleast making the  xmlns="" into xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"?